# Регулярка в BAT/CMD возможно?

Tags: регулярные-выражения, cmd, bat

`^(.*?)(:|;)(.*?){32,150}$` как такую регулярку можно в батнике использовать или вообще нельзя использовать регулярки? или надо может изменить под батник ?

Comment: Где выхотите применять ее? findstr - умеет с ними работать.

Comment: FINDSTR /R /I "^(.*?)(:|;)(.*?){32,150}$"

Comment: `findstr` поддерживает очень ограниченный набор возможностей регулярных выражений. Например, нельзя использовать ограничивающие квантификаторы `{m,n}`

Comment: блин а как то по другому можно найти батником строки  где длинна после : от 32 символов

Comment: [Дли**н**а](https://kak-pravilno.net/dlina-ili-dlinna-kak-pravilno/). Можно написать `:................................`. :)

Comment: ну кое как выход из положения ищет с точками этими  ну только не диапазон длинны , а число 32 символа или скок точек поставишь , но лучше чем нечего )) спасибо

Answer (score 0):

Если учесть что Batch Script почти ни чего не умеет кроме перенаправления пайпов из одних программ в другие, то можно рядом положить что то типа pgrep и использовать его или использовать powershell и вызвать из bat что то типа

```
powershell -NoProfile -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -Command "& { 'PowerShell' -match 'p.{2}e\w' }"
```

- `-NoProfile -ExecutionPolicy Bypass` могут быть не обязательны